# Sort not working using dbOpenDynaset in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I sort the name of the wine in asc order using dbOpenDynaset

Here is my vba code

```
Dim critère As String
Dim strFormateDesNomVins As String

Dim maBase       As Database
Dim tblVins      As Recordset

Set maBase = CurrentDb()
Set tblVins = maBase.OpenRecordset("tblVins", dbOpenDynaset)

critère = "[NoTypeVin]=" & typeVin
tblVins.Sort = "NomVin ASC"
tblVins.FindFirst critère
Do Until tblVins.NoMatch
     strFormateDesNomVins = strFormateDesNomVins & tblVins!NomVin & vbCrLf
    tblVins.FindNext critère
Loop
```

This part of the code does not work

```
tblVins.Sort = "NomVin ASC"
```

I want to sort the name of wine in asc order How can I do this using dbOpenDynaset Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot sort a table through VBA, generally you would create a form, report or query and sort that.

Comment: @Warcupine Is there than a way a can convert the code to tableDefs instaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but you must assign the sorted recordset to a (new) recordset and then use that:

```
tblVins.Sort = "NomVin ASC"
Set tblVins = tblVins.OpenRecordset()
```

or:

```
Set tblVinsSorted = tblVins.OpenRecordset()
```

or create it sorted initially:

```
Set tblVins = maBase.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblVins Order By NomVin", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use `.Sort` and `.FindFirst/.FindNext`, it is better to open a recordset that is already filtered and ordered as you want:

```
Sub sWine()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strFormateDesNomVins As String
    Dim typeVin As Long
    typeVin = 1
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT NomVin FROM tblVins WHERE NoTypeVin=" & typeVin & " ORDER BY NomVin ASC;"
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        Do
            strFormateDesNomVins = strFormateDesNomVins & rsData!NomVin & vbCrLf
            rsData.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsData.EOF
    End If
    Debug.Print strFormateDesNomVins
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the example above, I am creating a recordset that is based on `tblVins`, sorted by `NomVin`, and only having records where `NoTypeVin` is equal to `typeVin` (in this case 1).
Regards